# Render reports in R markdown

Tags: r

I need help in Rmarkdown.

I'm using Rmarkdown to generate reports one by one, by selecting the activity that i want (select in params when i click in knitr with parameters), but i have 40 activity and i want to execute it in one click and have 40 pdf reports, how can i do this ?

my params are used in path and in filter.

This is an idea of code that i use:

First; the params ( i just select two)

```
    ---
    title: "Graphics"
    author: "AliAnis"
    date: "19/07/2021"
    output:
      pdf_document:
        fig_caption: yes
        fig_height: 6
        fig_width: 7
      word_document: default
    params:
      da_aso:
        choices:
        - D01-C
        - D01-M
    ---
```

second; an idea of the path

```
path='XXXX/XXX/XX/XXX/XXXXX/'

LEN__Evol = read.csv2(paste0(path,'LEN__',params$da_aso,'__Evol.csv' ))
names(LEN__Evol)[2:4] = str_sub(colnames(LEN__Evol[2:4]), -4)
names(LEN__Evol)[5] = paste0('%(',str_sub(colnames(LEN__Evol[5]), -5), ')')
kable(LEN__Evol)
LEN__Evol_Valo = read.csv2(paste0(path,'LEN__',params$da_aso,'__Evol_Valo.csv' ))
names(LEN__Evol_Valo)[2:4] = str_sub(colnames(LEN__Evol_Valo[2:4]), -4)
names(LEN__Evol_Valo)[5] = paste0('%(',str_sub(colnames(LEN__Evol_Valo[5]), -5), ')')
kable(LEN__Evol_Valo)
```

Maybe a loop ? or using RENDER ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is code I have used sucessfully to generate site-specific data reports:

```
outputFolder <-  "<your path here>"
rootFolder <-  "<your path here>"

# Run the data quality checks
lapply(
  activeSites,
  function(site) {
    if (dir.exists(outputFolder)) {
      fileName <- paste0("/validationReport_", site, "_", dateString)
      print(paste0("Writing validation report to ", fileName, " ..."))
      rmarkdown::render(
        input=paste0(rootFolder, "/validationReportTemplate.Rmd"),
        output_file=fileName,
        output_dir=outputFolder,
        params=list(siteID=site)
      )
    } else {
      print(paste0("Ooops!  Output folder [", outputFolder, "] does not exist!"))
    }
    invisible(TRUE)
  }
)
```

The YAML header of `validationReportTemplate.Rmd` looks like this:

```
---
title: "Data quality report report for site `r params$siteID`"
author: "<Your name here>"
date: "Last run on `r Sys.Date()` by `r Sys.info()[['user']]` on `r Sys.info()[['nodename']]`"
output: html_document
params:
  siteID: "008"
  comments: NA
---
```

You can make obvious changes to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for replying, but what is activeSites ?

Comment: It's the list of sites for which I want to generate the report.  In your case, I assume it would be a list of activities.  I'm guessing it would be a list of unique values of a column in `LEN__Evol`.  This is an example of why it is so helpful (and important) to provide us with a minimum *reroducible* example.  You haven't provided any test data, so your code is not reproducible, and so anyone who answers has to guess or make something up.

Comment: there is no relation with the data, i have a multiple csv file, each csv file is 'LEN__',params$da_aso,'__Evol.csv'. I want to read.csv file in a pdf report, how can i do a function that say for each activity (params$da_aso) create a report by execute my file.rmd for exemple:  da_aso:
        - D01-C
        - D01-M